# What is the standard (or best supported) big number (arbitrary precision) library for Lua?

Tags: math, lua, precision, bignum

I'm working with large numbers that I can't have rounded off.  Using Lua's standard math library, there seem to be no convenient way to preserve precision past some internal limit.  I also see there are several libraries that can be loaded to work with big numbers:

1. http://oss.digirati.com.br/luabignum/
2. http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html
3. http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2002-02/msg00312.html (might be identical to #2)
4. http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?general=lua_bc (but I can't find any source)

Further, there are [many libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Arbitrary-precision_software) in C that could be called from Lua, if the bindings where established.

Have you had any experience with one or more of these libraries?

Comment: I've written Lua bindings for several big number libraries: lbc, lbn, lint64, lmapm, lqd, all available at http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/. They have different features and requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [lmapm library](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lmapm) by Luiz Figueiredo, one of the authors of the Lua language.

Answer (score 19):

Using [lbc](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/#lbc) instead of lmapm would be easier because lbc is self-contained.

```
local bc = require"bc"
s=bc.pow(2,1000):tostring()
z=0
for i=1,#s do
        z=z+s:byte(i)-("0"):byte(1)
end
print(z)
```

Comment: All my big number libraries have been updated and are now self-contained. See http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/ .

Answer (score 8):

I used Norman Ramsey's suggestion to solve Project Euler problem [#16](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=16).  I don't think it's a spoiler to say that the crux of the problem is calculating a 303 digit integer accurately.

Here are the steps I needed to install and use the library:

1. Lua needs to be built with dynamic loading enabled.  I use Cygwin, but I changed `PLAT` in `src/Makefile` to be `linux`.  The default, `none`, doesn't enable dynamic loading.
2. The [MAMP](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html) needs to be built and installed somewhere that your C compiler can find it.  I put `libmapm.a` in `/usr/local/lib/`.  Next `m_apm.h` and `m_apm_lc.h` went to `/usr/local/include/`.
3. The makefile for [lmamp](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lmapm) needs to be altered to the correct location of the Lua and MAMP libraries.  For me, that means uncommenting the second declaration of `LUA`,  `LUAINC`, `LUALIB`, and `LUABIN` and editing the declaration of `MAMP`.
4. Finally, `mapm.so` needs to be placed somewhere that Lua will find it.  I put it at `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/`.

Thank you all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 6):

I can't really answer, but I will add [LGMP](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-07/msg00560.html), a GMP binding. Not used.

Not my field of expertise, but I would expect the GNU multiple precision arithmetic library to be quite a standard here, no?

Comment: Ah.  That's helpful as the GMP documentation does not list it: http://gmplib.org/manual/Language-Bindings.html#Language-Bindings

Answer (score 5):

Though not *arbitrary* precision, [Lua decNumber](http://luaforge.net/projects/ldecnumber/), a Lua 5.1 wrapper for IBM decNumber, implements the proposed General Decimal Arithmetic standard IEEE 754r. It has the Lua 5.1 arithmetic operators and more, full control over rounding modes, and working precision up to 69 decimal digits.

Comment: 69?  That's about a third as many as I need. (I'm working on <http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=16>.)

Comment: @JonEricson You do realize you can use modular arithmetic to solve such problems? What if you were asked to find the sum of the digits of 7^3432566663432? Would your program work?

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries for the problem, each one with your advantages
and disadvantages, the best choice depends on your requeriments. I would say
[lbc](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/#lbc) is a good first pick if it
fulfills your requirements or any other by Luiz Figueiredo. For the most efficient one I guess would be any using GMP bindings as GMP is a standard C library for dealing with large integers and is very well optimized.

Nevertheless in case you are looking for a pure Lua one, [lua-bint](https://github.com/edubart/lua-bint)
library could be an option for dealing with big integers,
I wouldn't say it's the best because there are more efficient
and complete ones such the ones mentioned above, but usually they requires compiling C code
or can be troublesome to setup. However when comparing pure Lua big integer libraries
and depending in your use case it could perhaps be an efficient choice. The library is documented,
code fully covered by tests and have many examples. But take this recommendation with grant of
salt because I am the library author.

To install you can use luarocks if you already have it in your computer or simply download the
[bint.lua](https://github.com/edubart/lua-bint/blob/master/bint.lua)
file in your project, as it has no other dependencies other than requiring Lua 5.3+.

Here is a small example using it to solve the problem #16 from Project Euler
(mentioned in previous answers):

```lua
local bint = require 'bint'(1024)
local n = bint(1) << 1000
local digits = tostring(n)
local sum = 0
for i=1,#digits do
  sum = sum + tonumber(digits:sub(i,i))
end
print(sum) -- should output 1366
```