# How do I limit numbers in Lua while keeping precision?

Tags: lua, numbers, limit

Original Message:

> I need to multiply two 64 bit numbers, but Lua is losing precision
>   with big numbers.   (for example 99999999999999999 is shown as
>   100000000000000000)   After multiplying I need a **64 bit solution**,
>   so I need a way to limit the solution to 64 bits.   (I know, if the
>   solution would be precise, I could just use *% 0x10000000000000000*,
>   so that would work too)

**EDIT:** With Lua 5.3 and the new 64 bit integer support, this problem doesn't exist anymore. Neat.

Comment: My suggestion is to modify the source code and get your own type in the interpreter. Most cases you will embed the customized interpreter anyway

Comment: @texasbruce: There's no need to *modify the interpreter*; that's way overkill. You can add types without directly modifying the interpreter at all. Just create a module that you expose to Lua.

Comment: Note also that you need 128 bits to represent the product of two 64-bit numbers.

Comment: Not if you want a 64 bit result anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua uses double-precision floating points for all math, including integer arithmetic (see http://lua-users.org/wiki/FloatingPoint). This gives you about 53 bits of precision, which (as you've noticed) is less than you need.

There are a couple of different ways to get better precision in Lua. Your best bet is to find the most active such effort and piggy-back off it. In that case, your question has already been answered; check out [What is the standard (or best supported) big number (arbitrary precision) library for Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288707/what-is-the-standard-or-best-supported-big-number-arbitrary-precision-librar)

If your Lua distribution has packages for it, the easy answer is [lmapm](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lmapm).

Comment: If the OP only needs to handle integers, then using [lbc](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbc) instead of lmapm would be easier because lbc is self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/) in place of Lua, you get access to all C99 built-in types, including `long long` which is usually 64 bits.

```
local ffi = require 'ffi'

-- Needed to parse constants that do not fit in a double:
ffi.cdef 'long long strtoll(const char *restrict str, char **restrict endptr, int base);'

local a = ffi.C.strtoll("99999999999999999", nil, 10)
print(a)
print(a * a)
```

=> `3803012203950112769LL` (assuming the result is truncated to 64 bits)

Comment: I believe luajit supports the LL postfix for number literals.