# How to return very long integer in Lua

Tags: parsing, lua, return, steam

I am trying to return very long integer number but my result returns as
"7.6561197971049e+016".
How do I make it return 76561197971049296 ?

```
local id64 = 76561197960265728
Z = string.match("STEAM_0:0:5391784", 'STEAM_%d+:%d+:(%d+)')
Y = string.match("STEAM_0:0:5391784", 'STEAM_%d+:(%d+):%d+')
--For 64-bit systems
--Let X, Y and Z constants be defined by the SteamID: STEAM_X:Y:Z.
--Let V be SteamID64 identifier of the account type (0x0110000100000000 in hexadecimal format).
--Using the formula W=Z*2+V+Y
if Z == nil then
    return "none"
else
    return Z*2+id64+Y
end
```

I installed lbc arbitrary precision now with this code

```
return  bc.add(bc.number(id64),bc.number(2)):tostring()
```

it returns 70000000000000002 but if I delete 3 digits from id64 it displays correctly.

How can I get correct result without deleting the digits?

Comment: Thank you so much @lhf for the tip to extract with a single match and also for showing how to pass as a string to bc. That worked!

Comment: If your long ints fit in 64 bits, try my lint64, available at http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lint64, which is smaller and simpler than lbc.

Comment: Yes they do, I am using your lint64 library now, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use strings for long numbers. Otherwise, the Lua lexer converts them to doubles and loses precision in this case. Here is code using my lbc:

```
local bc=require"bc"
local id64=bc.number"76561197960265728"
local Y,Z=string.match("STEAM_0:0:5391784",'STEAM_%d+:(%d+):(%d+)')
if Z == nil then
    return "none"
else
    return (Z*2+id64+Y):tostring()
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your implementation of Lua supports that many significant digits in the `number` type, your return statement is returning that result.

You're probably seeing exponential notation when you convert the number to a string or printing it. You can use the `string.format` function to control the conversion:

```
assert( "76561197971049296" == string.format("%0.17g", 76561197971049296))
```

**If `number` is an IEEE-754 double, then it doesn't work.** You do have to know how your Lua is implemented and keep in mind the the technical limitations.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't support, I had to install lbc arbitrary precision library and now I have that problem I commented to collapsar.

Comment: Too bad 76561197971049296 needs 57 bits and doubles only give you 53.

Comment: Argh, the test in my answer works at [Lua Demo](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo). But, I should have tried `assert( 76561197971049296 == 76561197971049296 - 1)`, which doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

check out [this library](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbc) for arbitrary precision arithmetics. [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288707/what-is-the-standard-or-best-supported-big-number-arbitrary-precision-librar) might be of interest to you as well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the library, there is something i don't understand now with this code: bc.add(id64,2):tostring() it returns 70000000000000002 why so? id64 is 76561197960265728.

Comment: use `bc.add(id64,bc.number(2)):tostring()`.

Comment: It still returns 70000000000000002, I also tried this. bc.add(bc.number(id64),bc.number(2)):tostring()

Answer (score 1):

If you have `luajit` installed, you can do this:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

steamid64 = tostring(ffi.new("uint64_t", 76561197960265728) + ffi.new("uint64_t", tonumber(accountid)))
steamid64 = string.sub(steamid64, 1, -4) -- to remove 'ULL at the end'
```

Hope it helps.