# How can I work with numbers larger than 2^1024 in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to replicate some encryption methods in Lua and Lua doesn't like big numbers. For example:

```
print(6219^3445)
> inf
```

Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: It's not a good idea to roll your own crypto, especially if this is a system for use in production. Find some Lua-C bindings for a tried-and-true library.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288707/what-is-the-standard-or-best-supported-big-number-arbitrary-precision-librar, one of the first Lua questions here.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Lua-Library like:
http://oss.digirati.com.br/luabignum/

For encryption, you might want to have a look at the openssl-bindings for lua, perhaps these already contain what you are trying to implement:
http://luacrypto.luaforge.net/ or https://github.com/zhaozg/lua-openssl

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add this but with the circumstances I'm in I can't really  use a library. It's not executing in the regular Lua interpreter.

Comment: @tjpc3TheRedstoner That's OK for testing, or maybe some experiments. But in production it's a big no-no.

Comment: It's not for production. I guess I'll have to tell what I'm using it for. I'm trying to replicate RSA encryption (among other things) in Minecraft using OpenComputers (A computer mod) in lua.

Comment: "For those who are familiar with LUA structures" (bignum) I turned around and never looked back once I read 'LUA'

Answer (score 0):

Well. A really stupid (but effective) way could be to hold your numbers in strings, and in math operations deal with each digit separately. Concatenate for tostring.