# Dealing with big numbers in Lua

Tags: lua

I am in need to store a large number in Lua, for example the number 63680997318088143281752740767766707563546963464218564507450892460763521488675430192536461.

If I simple assign to a variable, I don't get the actual number:

```
local n = 63680997318088143281752740767766707563546963464218564507450892460763521488675430192536461
print(string.format("%.0f",n)) -- prints 63680997318088143929455344863959288468423333130904105158115881995380577784972357899649024
```

What would be the possible turn arounds to handle large numbers?

Comment: If you just want to store the numbers, use strings.

Comment: Thank you for the comment professor. On my case that huge number is result of a series of sum operations, so just storing as string was not option. I was able to successfully get that number correctly using the BigNum library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lua numbers have limited precision, but you are trying to store a number that exceeds what can be stored. You'll need to use a different mechanism to store them and operate on these numbers.

The key words are "bignum" and "arbitrary precision numbers". Quick google search returns several pure-Lua modules ([bignum](https://github.com/ennorehling/euler/blob/master/BigNum.lua) and [lua-nums](https://github.com/user-none/lua-nums)) and one C-based one ([lmapm](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lmapm)). Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288707/what-is-the-standard-or-best-supported-big-number-arbitrary-precision-librar) for other options.