# How to deal with the problem of insufficient precision of lua floating point numbers

Tags: lua

When using lua to handle floating point numbers I found that lua can handle very limited precision, for example:

```
print(3.14159265358979)
```

output:

```
3.1415926535898
```

The result will be missing a few decimal places, which will lead to calculation bias. How can I deal with such a lack of precision

Comment: You can read about how numbers are represented in LUA [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html).  And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270543/dealing-with-big-numbers-in-lua) has some answers with tips on LUA modules that can let you use numbers with more precision.

Comment: `print(("%.17g"):format(3.14159265358979))`

Comment: "*very limited precision*" I would not call 12 decimal places "very limited precision".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Lua only displays 14 digits of a number. A float can require 15 to 17 digits to be represented exactly as a base-10 string. We can use a loop to find the right number of digits. Note that `%g` will drop the trailing zeros, so we can start our search at 15 digits, not 1. This is the function I use:

```
local function floatToString(x)
  for precision = 15, 17 do
    -- Use a 2-layer format to try different precisions with %g.
    local s <const> = ('%%.%dg'):format(precision):format(x)
    -- See if s is an exact representation of x.
    if tonumber(s) == x then
      return s
    end
  end
end

print(floatToString(3.14159265358979))
```

Output: `3.14159265358979`